# How to get element to fill 100% height of parent

Tags: html, css

I have a simple horizontal menu.  Using CSS `display:table` and `display:table-cell`, I've made the menu "justified".  When the menu gets narrow enough, the text in some of the `<a>` elements wraps onto 2 lines, thereby increasing the height of those items.  The rest of the unwrapped `<a>`elements stay at the height of 1 line of text, ruining the effect.  How do I make all the `<a>` elements fill up 100% of the height of their containing `<li>`?

Limitations:

- Can't use Javascript to dynamically calculate the height
- Can't use Flexbox, as some supported browsers don't support Flexbox

I have an example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cyJEt?editors=110 , using this code:

```html
<ul class = "nav-mega">
  <li>
    <a href = "#">Two words</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href = "#">More words</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href = "#">Word</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href = "#">Word</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href = "#">More words</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href = "#">End</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```css
.nav-mega {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;

}
.nav-mega > li {
  display: table-cell;
  min-width: 10%;
  background:green;
}
.nav-mega > li a {
  display: block;
  background:red;
  outline:1px solid black;
  padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: give the background-color and border-bottom to li, and border-right to li>a.

Comment: @Hareesh That will give the proper appearance for sure, but the hit zone of the link will still not fill the .nav-mega

Comment: did you try height 100%, its working for me. li>a fills entire hit area when menu gets narrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.nav-mega {
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
 }
.nav-mega > li {
 display: table-cell;
 min-width: 10%;
 background:green;
 height:100%
}
.nav-mega > li a {
  display: block;
 background:red;
 outline:1px solid black;
 padding:10px;
 height:100%
}
```

adding height 100% to all parents up to html will work

Comment: That did it - thanks.  Weird how setting a height of .nav-mega affected the rendered height of .nav-mega > li a.

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to shuffle where you were adding attributes.

Put the background and outline on the li instead of the a.

```
.nav-mega > li {
  display: table-cell;
  min-width: 10%;
  background:green;
   background:red;
  outline:1px solid black;
}
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uvhze)

Comment: That will give the proper appearance for sure - but the hit zone for the link won't fill the height like I want.